# Why are the new leaves of my poly elephant’s ear turning yellow?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-care, indoors, alocasia

I just purchased a Poly Elephant’s Ear from my local nursery. It was in good condition prior to taking it home ( no yellowing of leaves). 3 days later, I noticed two new baby leaves have turned yellow/starting yellow. I position my plant in a corner area on the side of my window, so it gets indirect light. And the past 3 days the baby yellow leaves were facing the wall, while the bigger leaves were facing the light. What are some possible causes of the yellowing? TIA.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the elephant's ear grows new shoots in the centre of the growing tip, so since the yellowing leaves appear to be on the outside and fairly small compared to the younger bigger leaves in the middle likely those yellowing leaves are just old and have done their work and will dry up and disappear. All normal so far, just cut those dying leaves off.

Also the elephant's ear is a taro root plant, so hidden in that pot is a fleshy root which, as the plant gets bigger, takes up a lot of room displacing the soil needed for the plant to make new growth. The yellowing leaves could be a sign that the roots have almost exhausted the nutrients in that soil and it quite urgently needs to be moved into a larger pot with more rich soil if it is to continue healthy growth.

Comment: Can the fleshy root be trimmed instead of moving it to a larger pot?